# how to copy top 1000 records from 7000 records in existing table to other new table in postgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to copy the top 1000 records from one table to another(new) table using PostgreSQL.

I have tried

CREATE TABLE mycopy AS
SELECT * FROM mytable;

But not sure about 1000 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `limit`:

```
CREATE TABLE mycopy AS
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    LIMIT 1000;
```

However, if you want these in a particular order, then you need to use `ORDER BY`.  For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE mycopy AS
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 1000;
```

would return the first 1000 based on the order of the `id` column.

Comment: It fails saying

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE user AS SELECT * FROM people limit 10000;

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, the query works. it's just The word user is a reserved word in Postgres.